# Linux drawing to display without desktop manager

Tags: linux, opengl

Lets say i have a Linux (Ubuntu), well NVIDIA packaged one that comes with Jetson boards, and i have HDMI output and DP.

The goal is to: Display Desktop part via HDMI, and display GUI that i made with OpenGL via DP, but without DP ever showing Desktop, if process with GUI exits, the display connected via DP does not show anything until process is restarted.

So far i have researched X server, but most of the materials just talk about X11 protocol, and how to create a window. If i just open a window in full-screen mode, it could work, but until GUI is launched i would see part of Ubuntu desktop there.

The GUI is basically a Monitor with CT Overlay that sends touch input via I2C.

Comment: It looks like you confuse "desktop manager" (like gnome), "window manager" (like metacity) and "window system" (such as X11), You don't need the first two, but without X11 or Wayland things do get tricky. I think it can be done with DirectFB but I have no experience with it. See https://github.com/mcdoh/glGears-on-DirectFB-with-OpenGL-ES/

Comment: Interesting question, I don't know the answer but here's another link that can help: https://www.harrisgeospatial.com/Support/Self-Help-Tools/Help-Articles/Help-Articles-Detail/ArtMID/10220/ArticleID/19193/OpenGL-Direct-Hardware-Rendering-on-Linux

Comment: Try this: `cat /dev/urandom > /dev/fb0`. If there appears noise on your display, you can write to it by directly writing to the framebuffer. In `/sys/class/graphics/fb0/*` you can find some descriptors of the format / size. Of course those paths can vary slightly between different distro's, but this is the most straight-forward way that *usually* works.

Comment: @MarkJansen yeah, but then the tty will put stuff in it also, and i will end uo having console lines drawing there as well

Comment: So you are using a window manager or windowing system.

Comment: @MarkJansen i rewrote the whole question to clarify it.